# How to connect three columns in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a user table. Now, a user can be either a lender or a borrower. Both of them can have multiple loans. Now I want to create a relation between these three tables.
Here's what I want.

```
# A user can be a lender or borrower
# Both lenders and borrowers can have multiple loans.
# One borrower can have one loan only (typical one-to-one relationship).
# One loan can belong to multiple lenders. (later I want to distribute the loan).
```

I also tried polymorphic relations but those belong to only one table. But I want a single loan to be for one borrower and multiple lenders.

Now, How do I do this in laravel eloquent?

Comment: so lender or borrower is a role of user. and user can only be borrower or lender? this is one to one relationship. then one user can have many loans but one loan is associated with only one user?

Comment: @r89human well, one loan is associated with one borrower but with many lenders.